# If $f$ is a positive integrable function on $(X,\mu)$, why is $\int_0^\infty\mathbb 1_{\{x\in X: f(x)>t\}}(y)dt=\int_0^{f(y)}1dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> If $f$ is a positive integrable function on $(X,\mu)$, why is $\int_0^\infty\mathbb 1_{\{x\in X: f(x)>t\}}(y)dt=\int_0^{f(y)}1dt$ ?
>
> the exercise was, to show the equality between these 2 quantities:
>
> $\int_0^\infty\mu(\{f>t\})dt=\int_Xf\;d\mu$

Then, however i found the solution, but i don't understand the step, which i wrote below, can somebody explain it ?

$
\int_0^\infty\mu(\{f>t\})dt=\int_0^\infty\int_{X}\mathbb 1_{\{x\in X: f(x)>t\}}(y)\;d\mu(y)\;dt$
$$=\int_{X}\int_0^\infty\mathbb 1_{\{x\in X: f(x)>t\}}(y)\;dt\;d\mu(y)$$

$$(WHY??)=\int_X\int_0^{f(y)}dt\;d\mu(y)$$
$$=\int_Xf(y)\;d\mu(y)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\mu\left(\{x:f(x)\gt t\}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_0^\infty\int_X\mathbf{1}_{\{x:f(x)\gt t\}}(y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_X\,[f(y)\gt t]\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_X\int_0^{f(y)}\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\\
&=\int_Xf(y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)
\end{align}
$$
Using [Iverson Brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\mu\left(\{x:f(x)\gt t\}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_0^\infty\int_X\mathbf{1}_{\{x:f(x)\gt t\}}(y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_X\,[f(y)\gt t]\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_X\int_0^\infty\,[f(y)\gt t]\,\mathrm{d}t,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Here we consider the inner integral $\int_0^\infty\,[f(y)\gt t]\,\mathrm{d}t$ for a fixed y, then we count all t's for which the inequality holds, but this must give $\int_0^{f(y)-\epsilon}1\mathrm{d}t$ but $\int_0^\epsilon 1\mathrm{d}t$ is irrelevant, so the claim follows.



$$=\int_X\int_0^{f(y)}\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)\\
=\int_Xf(y)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)
$$

Can you confirm this ?

Comment: @derivative: Yes, I originally had the line
$$
\int_X\int_0^\infty\,[f(y)\gt t]\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}\mu(y)
$$
but I combined it with the next step.

Comment: @derivative: your comments looks correct.